# How to raise an exception when bulk inserting faulty rows into crateDB using Python Pandas to_sql()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cratedb

I am bulk inserting data into crateDB using

```
pandas.to_sql(tableId, 'crate://xxxxxxx:4200', if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=20000)
```

The data contains a few faulty rows where one column of type 'numeric' contains a value of type 'object' / 'string'.

This results in a typecasting error while inserting.

When I set the chunksize parameter of to_sql() to 1, an exception is raised and I can catch the issue.

When chunksize is > 0, `to_sql()` just continues and I cannot make sure that data was inserted properly.

What am I missing, and what would be a good approach to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem most likely is that pandas doesn't return anything on `to_sql()` also see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23998 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42645 .  Since the bulk_insert in CrateDB doesn't completely fail, but only skips the faulty rows, no exception is raised, but only an array with a value per row is returned. That return however never is processed in pandas :/

One could change the SQL alchemy implementation of CrateDB, but this would in return break any implementation that actually uses the results array.

Answer (score 0):

For bulk inserts you need to inspect the result of the query for error handling. It includes an array of `rowcounts`. A `-2` indicates that an error occurred.

For specific errors, likely including typecasting errors, all rows will be rejected (i.e. all rowcounts return -2) in which case you will need to fall back to single inserts.

See https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/4.6/interfaces/http.html#bulk-errors for additional details.

Comment: Thanks. This applies for the http REST API. When using to_sql(), None is always returned, nothing to inspect unfortunately.